# Normalization in case of clustering

Tags: clustering, normalization

Can normalization in this form be used (x−μ)/σ and should it be used in case of clustering?

I have parameters on different scales and since I'm calculating the distances I need to perform feature scaling, but it seems that min-max clustering has more sense in this case?

Another thing to consider is that I have some parameters that have greater variability than the other ones and the change between their values should be considered equally important.

Also, new data may arrive and I need to calculate the distance to the existing centroids and new arrived data may have value that is greater than the max in the set on which clustering is performed.

---

Here is more detail about my problem:

- I have a certain number of parameters (currently 6, but that is not important, since I'm interested in the concept that does not depend on it)
- Some of the parameters in the training set have value in range of 0-1 (that is 0 or 1, parameters have discrete values,like number of orders of some product and can have greater positive values,like 5 or 10)
- Other parameters also have positive, discrete values, but they are somewhat greater and currently have values in range of 0-70 (this values can also happen to be greater) and they represent some cumulative, like products delivered and not used yet
- I'm performing Streaming K Means clustering method (it's distance based, of course)
- To avoid parameters that can have greater values and range being boosted I need to use some kind of normalization
- By performing clustering I generate centroids that represent a model of what is normal for my system
- Than, during time, I represent new data in a similar way and calculate the distance to existing centroids to detect if there is something strange (anomalous)
- To treat new data in the same way, I need to normalize it as well
- My first thought was min-max normalization which gives me all parameter values in a range [0,1], but the problem is that new coming data may have parameter values greater than values for same parameter in the training set, so I can have values that are greater than 1, and possibly encounter the problem that parameters with greater variability seem more important
- Also, since I'm running anomaly detection, I would like to find what seems to be the cause of the anomaly, that is, which parameter varies the most
- To find what parameter varies the most I again have the problem if some parameter has value greater than 1

So, should I use z-score normalization and why or why not?

This may be too much info (or maybe something else needs to be added) but it may help someone with a similar doubt.

Thanks

Comment: There is a lot of background here you didnt tell us, so please tell us your real problem.  There is nothing to build on in what you have given so far!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen ok, thank you for your interest, just tell me what information should I provide and I will do that?

Comment: What are your variables? how many observations do you have?  What is your goal, that is, given a model, what use will you put it to? And, what is your knowledge background?

Comment: Also, there is a heap of questions about `clustering standardization / normalization` already on the site. You might first try to browse them.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have update the question, can you reconsider the problem now?